# /give @p skull is not working

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This command is not giving me the the skull in Minecraft Pocket Edition:

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Popcorn"},SkullOwner:{Id:"11ad1a4f-ddba-4550-abd7-14288f367d90",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMTQ5N2IxNDdjZmFlNTIyMDU1OTdmNzJlM2M0ZWY1MjUxMmU5Njc3MDIwZTRiNGZhNzUxMmMzYzZhY2RkOGMxIn19fQ=="}]}}}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this command?

Comment: ...and what is your result when you try it? An error message? Pigs everywhere? Your house explodes?

Comment: First mistake spotted: You put `Skullowner` into the `display` tag. That's probably the error message you get (just a guess). Try changing that and if it still doesn't work, edit your question to answer the questions and giving as much information as possible. If it does work, please say that in a comment. Also, next time do research. I knew that `Skullowner` can't be in the `display` tag, but using the wiki you should also be able to find that out. Also, this looks like you copied NBT from somewhere. Can't you maybe just use `/entitydata` to change a single property of that item?

Comment: That command looks ok, but it's not for MCPE...

Answer (score 0):

As dly mentions in the comments, the command is fine.  It's not for pocket edition.

Here are the results in Java Edition 1.12.2:
[image: Head image]